# What exactly is Geometric Analysis?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question

I don't really know if here's a good place to ask this question, but I'd appreciate it if someone can guide me here so that I can choose the right path going forward! I recently got my masters degree and now I am trying to figure out what is best for me to do in my PhD and I have bunch of questions about Geometric Analysis and would be happy if professionals can help me through this!

1. What exactly is geometric analysis and what's the difference between this field and Differential Geometry?
2. What are the fundamental courses you need to go through to be called a geometric analyst?
3. What are its applications? Is it mostly applied in physics or does it also have some applications in the industry? If so, what are some examples of the projects in this field and can one apply it to machine learning for instance?

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: This question is worth a long answer, but one major distinction from the start is that differential geometry requires a smooth structure, which is often weakened only to piecewise smoothness. Geometric analysts often study spaces which may be formalized in terms of only continuity or measurability, both much weaker notions than differentiability.

Comment: Much of differential geometry has merged into geometric analysis (as opposed to local geometric computations). There are lots of different analytic tools you might need, but for starters you should get some background in PDE (partial differential equations). See, for example, all the work on curvature flow (Hamilton et al.). The previous comment alludes also to geometric measure theory, which is very much of a different flavor, concentrating on geometry on singular spaces, which are studied with the tools of distribution theory and currents.

Comment: Do you have a particular PhD advisor in mind that does Geometric Analysis? If you are looking for this information because you want to choose research field, it's probably best to talk to professor you would like to work with, because even within a particular field, there are so many different things you could pursue, and answers you might get here might not coincide with what you'd actually be doing for your research.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: @Ennar Not really. I'm not really successful in getting responses!

Comment: User-123, well even though you tried to narrow it, it's still somewhat of a broad question, it takes time to write an answer to such a question and any answer will be a shot in the dark, maybe it would be helpful to you, maybe it wouldn't. In such situations people are likely just to write something in comments. I'd recommend you start from wikipedia article, try to come up with more specific questions, consider adding more specific tags etc.